Visual Studio cannot find angular modules anymore After upgrading to a latest version. How to resolve this issue?
I recently upgraded my Visual Studio Community v17.6 to v17.9 and the visual studio is giving me error messages like this Cannot find module '@angular/core'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option? It appears visual studio cannot file modules anymore due to the latest upgrade. Conflicting typescript?
I didn't have any problem with the previous version. Everything was working fine. This only happened when I upgraded the version.
Project Details are as follows
Angular 14
.Net Core 3.1
Here's my tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2020",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}

My package.json as follows

More details about my Visual Studio

I do have a feeling that the typescript has messed up my project. The Project builds and works perfectly. Its that the errors and the IntelliSense that keeps bothering me.
Any help is greatly appreciated if you can resolve this issue for me.
